# PayPal REST API multiple buttons on a page in separate tables

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I have 3 separate tables, of which each one I want to have a specific paypal btn with a specific price.

I am having issues when creating the 2nd paypal btn. It un-renders the first btn and then only the second one exists. I am pretty sure the render() function I have isn't set up properly. I have read PayPals SDK documentations and there really isn't any info on this.

Below is my code:

html:

```
   <div class="container-fluid table-responsive services-container">
        <div>
            
            <table class="table table-striped table-dark">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col">
                            <p style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 26px;">Introduction to Programming (July)</p> 
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
             
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <p class="details">Product 1</p>
                    </td>

                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <h6 class="price">$500</h6>                         
                        <div id="paypal-button-container1"></div>                           
                    </td>           
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
                                
    </div>  
    <div class="container-fluid table-responsive services-container">
        <div>
            
            <table class="table table-striped table-dark">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col">
                            <p style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 26px;">Product 2</p>
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <h6 price class="price">$75</h6> 
                        <div id="paypal-button-container2"></div> 
                    </td>
                     
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
       
        <div class="container-fluid table-responsive services-container">
            <div>
                
                <table class="table table-striped table-dark">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="col">
                                <p style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 26px;">Product 3</p>
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <h6 class="price">$200</h6>
                            <div id="paypal-button-container3"></div> 
                        </td>
                         
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
                            
        </div>
```

js:

```
 paypal.Buttons({
style: {
    shape: 'rect',
    color: 'gold',
    layout: 'vertical',
    label: 'paypal',
                                
    },
     createOrder: function(data, actions) {
        return actions.order.create({
            purchase_units: [{
                amount: {
                    value: '500'
                }
            }]
        });
    },

    onApprove: function(data, actions) {
        return actions.order.capture().then(function(details) {
            alert('Transaction completed by ' + details.payer.name.given_name + '!');
        });
    }
}).render('#paypal-button-container1');
```

As you can see, the render(divID) is only rendering to one div, I want to potentially make 3 different renders to all 3 of the corresponding divs.

I have tried multiple of these paypal:Buttons functions, one for each product with different createOrder functions as well, but this also does not work.

So what do I do?

Can I put 3 separate createOrder functions with all 3 prices in it, but with just one render at the bottom how will it know which one to render with which price?

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you repeat that JS three times with different selectors (container1, container2, container3) and different purchase_unit objects with their own prices etc, it will work.

Comment: I have tried this I believe, but it did not work. I will try again as soon as I get home and keep you posted.